# updated Ubuntu webserver not working

Tags: server, upgrade, php, nginx, php7

I just updated an Ubuntu 16.04 server to 18.04 using `sudo do-release-upgrade`. Nginx is the webserver. Sites report 404. During install, I chose to keep the currently installed version.

```
$ ps aux | grep nginx
root      1477  0.0  0.0 141120  1568 ?        Ss   06:36   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data  1478  0.0  0.2 143752  6160 ?        S    06:36   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1479  0.0  0.2 143752  6160 ?        S    06:36   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

Nginx is running the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` is configured as it was.

PHP is also running:

```
$ ps aux | grep php
root      1319  0.0  0.5 290448 17208 ?        Ss   06:36   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data  1486  0.0  0.2 292744  7464 ?        S    06:36   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  1487  0.0  0.2 292744  7464 ?        S    06:36   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

When I navigate to the webpages content like text, or pdfs, or images using the full url, 
the content is displayed. but when I type the script names, or the webpage names its 404.

looking at the error log:

```
$ sudo tail -n 20 /var/log/nginx/error.log
2020/03/22 06:37:21 [crit] 1478#1478: *2 connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 141.114.192.156, server: DomainName, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.1.104"
```

(changed the IP, and wrote in the DomainName part) perhaps the server is looking for the wrong php version?

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 (cli) (built: Feb 11 2020 15:55:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
```

So then I realized that the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
is pointing to the wrong version of php. Fine, I changed it from php7.0 to php7.2. now I get "Access Denied" for the webpages.
here is my "default" setup:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /home/user/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server.name.omited.org;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        autoindex on;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /404.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /home/user/public_html;
    }

   location ~ \.php$|\.html|\.htm {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       # fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Ok I made slight progress, realizing that php7 was in the wrong version, I then realized I would also have to enable php7.2 on the server.

```
sudo systemctl enable php7.2-fpm
```

I still get access denied, for all the html webpages, but, the php webpages when accessed directly, will display the proper content.

I modified the `security.limit_extensions = .php .html` term in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909860/access-denied-on-nginx-and-php):
The index page now appears,the html, and php scripts both work. none of the links to other pages work, all of them still come up with "Access Denied"
 then I realized there are .htm pages.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it. Sweet relief!

When I updated (running `sudo do-release-upgrade`), I kept the installed version of NGINX, and I thought I would get a similar offer to keep or upgrade php7.0. That didn't happen. When the upgrade completed something happened to php7.0 rendering it useless.

I had to modify some files to get my server running again.
The files I edited were:
`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
`/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

I ran `sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-fpm  php-common php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-json php7.2-opcache` to update php7.2. It did the upgrade, to php7.2. The server reported a version of php7.2 prior to doing this step but it wasn't working, so I upgraded it anyway.

I then modified my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file to include the line:
`fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;`
this points the nginx to the version of php I have now installed.

then, I ran 
`sudo systemctl enable php7.2-fpm`
`sudo systemctl start php7.2-fpm`
to enable php7.2, and start it.

Php scripts now run, but only when accessed directly. html & htm pages with embedded php still aren't working at this step.

I tested my nginx config files with:
`sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl reload nginx`
 the nginx config files gave no errors. but at this step, the htm & html pages were still showing "Access Denied".

Next I modified line 389 of `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`
to include the line: `security.limit_extensions = .php .html .htm`

Then I restarted php7.2:
`sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service`

At this point the server was now behaving as I would expect: php script render html page components, htm, & html files render properly.
After this, my server was working

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a phpinfo file to see if php is parsed correctly?

`<?php
// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();`

Have you restarted/reloaded your php-fpm?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and it has the same problem. all of the html pages are comprised of php scripts, wraped in html. I think I might be pointiing to the wrong version of php.

Comment: Could you check your virtual domain file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to see if the location block `~ \.php$ { ` points to the right location?

Comment: The location block that you've added, looks ok. So it seems like nginx is trying to use the old php7.0-fpm.sock. 

Could you restart the whole server?